# How to split a post and intercalate elements from a loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, the-content

What I'm trying to achieve is spreading related posts throughout the content - such as one reccomendation after every 3 paragraphs.

As I see it, three things need be done:

1 - Do the loop. What I'm using now is something like this:

```
<?php
$related = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $whatever) );
if ( $related->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $related->have_posts() ) {
        $related->the_post();
        get_template_part('relatedpost');
    }
}
wp_reset_query();
```

2 - Split the post - I'm using this code, that works great for static content such as ads.

```
function insert_related_post( $text )
{
    if ( is_single() ) :
        $insert = '[ad]';
        $split_by = "</p>";
        $insert_after = 3; //number of paragraphs
        // make array of paragraphs
        $paragraphs = explode( $split_by, $text);
        $new_text = '';    // new text
        $i = 1;            // current ad index
        // loop through array and build string for output
        foreach( $paragraphs as $paragraph ) {
            // add paragraph, preceeded by an ad after every $insert_after
            $new_text .= ( $i % $insert_after == 0 ? $insert : '' ) . $paragraph;
            // increase index
            $i++;
        }
        return $new_text;
    endif;
    echo $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'insert_related_post');
```

3 - Insert each element in the loop after every third paragraph. That, I can't figure how to do.

I suppose that the iterations should look something like this...

```
<?php
$related = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__in'       => $whatever,
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'offset'         => $i++/3,
) );

if ( $related->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $related->have_posts() ) {
        $related->the_post();
        get_template_part('relatedpost');
    }
}

wp_reset_query();
```

...but I can't manage to have that work - so where/how could I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buffer the template part to use it within post content:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_related_each_nth_p' );

function add_related_each_nth_p( $content )
{
    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        return $content;
    }

    // the interval between added content
    $paragraph_steps = 3;

    // declare empty output
    $output = '';

    // declare related posts offset
    $z = 0;

    // make the array of paragraphs
    $content = explode( '</p>', $content );

    // iterate through the content paragraphs
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $content ); $i++ ) {

        // concatenate paragraphs one by one
        $output .=  $content[ $i ] . '</p>';

        // check if interval is reached and if so, concatenate related
        if ( 0 == $i % $paragraph_steps ) {

            // run your query
            $related = new WP_Query( array(
                'post__in'       => $whatever,
                'posts_per_page' => '1',
                'offset'         => $z,
            ) );

            // related post offset increments by one every interval
            $z++;

            if ( $related->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $related->have_posts() ) {

                    $related->the_post();
                    // start buffering
                    ob_start();
                    get_template_part('relatedpost');
                    // concatenate related post to the output
                    $output .= ob_get_contents();
                    // Clean the output buffer
                    ob_end_clean();
                }
            }
            wp_reset_query();
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Or you can move `relatedpost` template part markup to the function (see the appropriate place in the code above), for example:

```
<?php
if ( $related->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $related->have_posts() ) {
        $related->the_post();
        $output .= '<p>Related: ' . get_the_title() . '</p>';
    }
}
```

The code is not tested, though.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, putting everything where it should be. 
I still have a bit of trouble as it ignores my custom loop and just gets the latest posts instead, but I suppose that's probably just an issue with my code or some reset that I need to put in somewhere.

Comment: Solved by putting it in a template instead of functions.php, for me it's just as fine.

Comment: Yes, the template is a good idea.